# Need std code based on ip country to be prefix with phone field on woocommerce checkout field

Tags: woocommerce, ip, checkout, billing

https://dev.clipcertification.com/checkout/

I want to prefix std code with Phone field based on ip country, Eg: If user's ip country is india, there will be a field before Phone, which will display +91 and so on.

How to achieve? Please help

Comment: You should first need to subscribe to a service that will be able to give you the country for an IP via some API (I have no idea about that kind of service)… Once done, it will be easy to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are looking for this, but if you want to display default value for billing_phone for respected country. You can try this code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'override_default_billing_phone');
function override_default_billing_phone($fields){
  global $woocommerce;
  $country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();

  //your country goes here for example 'AE' for UAE
  if($country == 'AE'){
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['default'] = '+971'; //Here is the code for billing phone
  }
  return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, Bless you, you saved my butt